# Optimize a SQL request containing sub requests on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL request written in php that I would like to optimize.

I think it is possible because everything is in the same table. I'm not a SQL expert and my searchs withs keywords including "share" and "results"/"sub"/"partial" didn't help.

```
SELECT C0.bestScore, C1.playerScore, C2.playerRank FROM 
(SELECT MAX(score) AS bestScore FROM `{$l_tableName}`) C0,
(SELECT MAX(score) AS playerScore FROM `{$l_tableName}` WHERE player_id = {$l_playerId}) C1,
(SELECT COUNT(*)+1 AS playerRank FROM `{$l_tableName}` WHERE score > (SELECT MAX(score) FROM `{$l_tableName}` WHERE player_id = {$l_playerId}) ) C2;
```

Thanks

Comment: If you'r substituting PHP strings into SQL (which it looks like you are), *please don't* - it's insecure. If you're using the `mysql_*` functions, *please don't* - they're deprecated. Just use `mysqli` or PDO parameterised queries - you'll save yourself a lot of SQL-injection pain.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. However I read about this some months ago and I now use PDO. This code is a extracted sample part.
Do you think it can be speed up ?

Answer (score 1):

You could clean up the first 2 with this, not entirely sure about the third part, it's unclear what you're after, how can the score be greater than the max score from the same table?

```
SELECT MAX(score) AS bestScore
     , MAX(CASE WHEN player_id = {$l_playerId}) THEN score ELSE '' END) AS playerScore
FROM `{$l_tableName}`
```

Comment: Thank you for this good suggestion. The score can't be greater than the max score from the same table, you are right. I just want, from a given table, to know the best score among all players, the current player's score and the rank of the current player in the whole list of players.

Comment: Does each player have multiple scores?  If so, is there a gameID or date that can be used to differentiate?  To me it sounded like a comparison of a new score to existing scores, but if it's just one per person this is easier.

Comment: Each player has a single score in this table, could I reuse the MAX(score) variable you suggested for another request ?